# How to export and import snapshot of virtual machine instead of whole virtual machine disk - Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, export, import

Virtual machines can be exported using  File > Export Virtual Appliance. But, it exports Virtual machines a s a whole. Is there any change to export only incremental changes relative to base disk ?

Let's consider scenario, On computer (let's say B) there is already a based disk which identical to base disk of Virtual machine which on system A, but states are different.

Is there any change to sync state on machine B with state on Virtual Machine which on system A? or

Can you export and import only the incremental or differential state  or snapshot instead of whole virtual machine ?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Both windows & Linux. Virtualbox supports multiple platforms. So, it is expected to export and import virtual machines across different platforms

Comment: as you stated yourself, you have the export/import options for the whole VM. Additionally there is a copy disk option in the Virtual Media Manager, which probably will not suit you as it copies the whole disk, not the differences. If you could explain a bit more what you want to achieve. Backup? Prod 2 Dev? What about VM to VM sync? But in short, I would say No, not possible what you want to achieve with copying the differential disk.